# How to handle session creation and adding hidden input csrf token for any page containing a form for an anonymous user in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

***I Introduce the problem:***

when I launch the application and I enter the url "/home". The home page is displayed but not correctly (the template is not well organized) and I receive an exception **TemplateInputException**. After a while, If I refresh the home page and the other pages It comes back to normal but if I go to "/login", and I logout which redirects me to the home view the same issue comes back again.

***The Stacktrace Console:***

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
> during template parsing (template: "class path resource
> [templates/home.html]") ...
>
> **Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException**: Error during execution of processor
> 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor' (template:
> "home" - line 2494, col 10)   at
> org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
> ~[attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]...
>
> **Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException**: Error
> during execution of processor
> 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor' (template:
> "home" - line 2494, col 10)
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:** Cannot create a session after the response has been committed     at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2995)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
>
> ...
>
> at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.saveToken(HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.java:63)
> ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository$SaveOnAccessCsrfToken.saveTokenIfNecessary(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:176)
> ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository$SaveOnAccessCsrfToken.getToken(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:128)
> ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.**getExtraHiddenFields**(CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.java:71)
> ~[spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE] ...

***The Code source:***

The issue is in the Contact Form of the home.html in this line: `th:action="@{/home/contact}" th:object="${mailForm}"`:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/home/contact}" 
    th:action="@{/home/contact}" th:object="${mailForm}"
    role="form">
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" 
    value="${_csrf.token}" /> -->
    <input type="text" name="senderName" th:field="*{senderName}"> 
    <input type="text" name="senderLastName" th:field="*{senderLastName}">  
    <input type="email" name="senderEmail" th:field="*{senderEmail}">            
    <textarea name="message" th:field="*{message}"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

I think it's a problem with csrf token. I tried to add this line `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />` in my form and the csrf protection is enabled by default by Spring Security but it did not work.

The Controller that calls the service to send mails:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;
    @Autowired
    private MailValidator mailValidator;
    
    // some other code like @InitBinder methode ...
    
    // method to post mailForm
    @PostMapping("/home/contact")
    public String contactUsHome(@Valid @ModelAttribute("mailForm") final MailForm mailForm, BindingResult bindingResult)
            throws MessagingException {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return HOME_VIEW;
        } else {
            mailForm.setRecipientEmail(recipientEmail);
            Mail mail = DTOUtil.map(mailForm, Mail.class);
            emailService.sendSimpleMail(mail);
            return REDIRECT_HOME_VIEW;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to fix the issue "Cannot create a session and CSRF token".

In the spring security configuration class, I just added this line `.and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(..)` and everything works well.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.authorizeRequests()
     //some another line of code...
     .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository())
}
```